# Weird things with Switch Case Arduino

Tags: arduino, switch-statement, arduino-c++

Well I know it sounds pretty weird, but I made code in Arduino which works find when i just use an if statement for every different option. But that's what switch cases are for, so I tried it and for some weird reason it goes into and executes the code for `standbyStatus==0` and for `standbyStatus==1`, but for `standbyStatus==2` or in `default`, nothing is executed whatsoever. Note that the variable `standbyStatus` is set to `2` by the code for status `1`. I can check that over the serial monitor, but the test `Serial.print("case 2.1");` in the `2` -code doesn't appear. Only `END of standbymanager`. Again, when I use if, everything works as it should. Here is first the code with if and then the same code just as a switch case:

Also, that method is called over and over again. This is my loop.

```
void loop() 
{
  t= millis();
  newAudio();
  calcAudioScale();
  if(standbyStatus==0){changeLEDs();}
  standbymanager();
}
```

That method is basicly checking if there is some sound for like 40ms or sth, and if there is not, it'll change to standbyStatus One, which is a smooth dim up of the LEDs, which will be interrupted if there is sound, but if there isn't, it'll change to standbyStatus Two, which is just a solid light and checking just every second if there is sound. If so, it'll change back to stabdbyStatus zero.

Code #1 'IF':

```
void standbymanager()
{          
  if(standbyStatus==0)
  {
            Serial.print(" ");
            Serial.print("case0");
            if(audio[standbyTrigger]<0)
            {
              idleCounter++;
            }
            if(idleCounter>40)
            {
              standbyStatus = 1;
            }
  }

    if(standbyStatus==1)
  {
            Serial.print(" ");
            Serial.print("case1");
            idleCounter = 0;
            float power = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
            {
              if(audio[standbyTrigger]>0)
                {
                  standbyStatus = 0;
                  return;
                }
              power = i/100;
              analogWrite(red, 255 - r*power);
              analogWrite(green, 255 - g*power);
              analogWrite(blue, 255 - b*power);
              delay(20); 
            }
            standbyStatus = 2;
            return;
  }

    if(standbyStatus==2)
  {
            Serial.print(" ");
            Serial.print("case 2.1");
            if(audio[standbyTrigger]>10)
                {
                  standbyStatus = 0;
                  return;
                }
            analogWrite(red, 255 - r);
            analogWrite(green, 255 - g);
            analogWrite(blue, 255 - b);
            Serial.print(" ");
            Serial.print("case2.2");
            delay(1000);
           return;
  }
  Serial.print(" ");
            Serial.print("END of StandbyManager");
}
```

Code #2 'Switch Case'

```
void standbymanager()
{          
  switch(standbyStatus)
  {
    case 0:
            Serial.print(" ");
            Serial.print("case0");
            if(audio[standbyTrigger]<0)
            {
              idleCounter++;
            }
            if(idleCounter>40)
            {
              standbyStatus = 1;
            }
            break;

    case 1:
            Serial.print(" ");
            Serial.print("case1");
            idleCounter = 0;
            float power = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
            {
              if(audio[standbyTrigger]>0)
                {
                  standbyStatus = 0;
                  break;
                }
              power = i/100;
              analogWrite(red, 255 - r*power);
              analogWrite(green, 255 - g*power);
              analogWrite(blue, 255 - b*power);
              delay(20); 
            }
            standbyStatus = 2;
            break;

    case 2:
            Serial.print(" ");
            Serial.print("case 2.1");
            if(audio[standbyTrigger]>0)
                {
                  standbyStatus = 0;
                  break;
                }
            analogWrite(red, 255 - r);
            analogWrite(green, 255 - g);
            analogWrite(blue, 255 - b);
            Serial.print(" ");
            Serial.print("case2.2");
            delay(1000);
            break;

    default:
            standbyStatus=0;
            Serial.print(" ");
            Serial.print("default");
            delay(1000); 
            break;
  }
  Serial.print(" ");
            Serial.print("END of StandbyManager");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the errors come from `case 1`:

- variables can't be declared inside a `case` statement
- the `break` inside the `for` doesn't break from the `switch` statement

You can refactor it to:

```
case 1: 
{
        Serial.print(" ");
        Serial.print("case1");
        idleCounter = 0;
        float power = 0;
        bool flag = false;
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
          if(audio[standbyTrigger]>0)
            {
              standbyStatus = 0;
              flag = true;
              break;
            }
          power = i/100;
          analogWrite(red, 255 - r*power);
          analogWrite(green, 255 - g*power);
          analogWrite(blue, 255 - b*power);
          delay(20); 
        }
        if (flag == false) {
           standbyStatus = 2;
        }
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably changing `standbyStatus` 0 to 1 here:

```
if(standbyStatus==0)
{
            Serial.print(" ");
            Serial.print("case0");
            if(audio[standbyTrigger]<0)
            {
              idleCounter++;
            }
            if(idleCounter>40)
            {
              standbyStatus = 1;
            }
  }
```

then it's normal to enter this if statement:

```
if(standbyStatus==1)
{
            Serial.print(" ");
            Serial.print("case1");
            idleCounter = 0;
            float power = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
            {
              if(audio[standbyTrigger]>0)
                {
                  standbyStatus = 0;
                  return;
                }
              power = i/100;
              analogWrite(red, 255 - r*power);
              analogWrite(green, 255 - g*power);
              analogWrite(blue, 255 - b*power);
              delay(20); 
            }
            standbyStatus = 2;
            return;
  }
```

and second version of your code you use switch case, as the name suggest you only *select* one. Therefore `standbyStatus` will be updated but not going to enter other cases.

**Edit**:
Be aware that two codes are doing different things, code 1 can change `standbyStatus` and enter other if statements, and it returns after setting `standbyStatus`. Code 2 doesn't return in cases it only breaks the loop not entire case. Also Code 2 is not going to enter different blocks like in Code 1 (for single function call).

Comment: ah i should have mentioned, that this mathod is called over and over again...

Comment: then you need to debug your code by yourself, simply print the `standbyStatus` in top of `standbymanager()` and see what's happening.

Comment: I do that. And I see it changing to 2, but it won't go into the code I wrote for 2